# How to use patch request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

There is entity `User` that is stoted in table `Users`

Some fields in this table are null by default.

I need to update these fields and set not null data.

For this I try to use `PATCH` method in Laravel:

**Routing:**

```
Route::patch('users/update', 'UsersController@update');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "name" => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            "email_work" => 'email|max:255|unique:users',
            "surname" => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            "tel" => 'required|numeric|size:11',
            "country" => 'required|integer',
            "region" => 'required|integer',
            "city" => 'required|integer'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(["message" => $validator->errors()->all()], 400);
        }

        $user = User::where("user_id", $id)->update([
            "name" => $request->name,
            "surname" => $request->surname,
            "tel" => $request->tel,
            "country" => $request->country,
            "city" => $request->city,
            "region" => $request->region,
            "email_work" => $request->email
        ]);

        return response()->json(["user" => $user]);

    }
```

Does it mean that I can pass any data to update?
Should I pass `$id` parameter to routing and controller relatively?

How to use right handler for PATCH method in Laravel?

Comment: Could you run `php artisan route:list` and show us what it tells you about this specific route that you registered?

Comment: if you have $id parameter in update() function, then i suppose you need to add `{id}` your route, like this `Route::patch('users/{id}/update', 'UsersController@update');`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Using single route :

```
Route::patch('users/{id}', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
```

**Or** Using resource route :

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

If you want use in `jQuery.ajax()`:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "{{ url('/users/') }}" + id,
    data: {"_method": "PATCH", ...}
    ...
});
```

If you want use in html form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.update',['id' => $id]) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
</form>
```

Comment: then when can we use `method="PATCH"` in Laravel blade forms? I just noticed it's not working for me too if I use Patch method in form.

Comment: @AmitShah from the Laravel documentation: HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to send id for route patch. Example from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers for Laravel

PUT/PATCH  - /photos/{photo}, so you don't need `update` word in your route. Just users/id and methods PUT or PATCH.

UPD for CRUD operations:

```
// Routes
Route::resource('items', 'ItemsController');

// Form for update item with id=1
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('items.update', ['id' => 1])}}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
    <!-- Your fields here -->
</form>

// Controller
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    // Validation here

    $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

    // Update here
}
```

Comment: Could you share a real sample?

Comment: Thank you Man! It helps me to set multiple parameters to update form action.

Answer (score 3):

Update the routing as per below

```
Route::patch('/users/update/{id}',[
    'uses' => 'UsersController@update'
]);
```

Comment: In my case I get `id` in controller from Auth object