# Not update categories table in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.6 and MySQL. I am going to update categoryname and image in my categories table using the following controller  function?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    if ($request->isMethod('get'))
        return view('categories.form', ['image' => Category::find($id)]);

    else {
        $rules = [
            'categoryname' => 'required',
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);
        $image = Category::find($id);
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $dir = 'images/';
            if ($image->image != '' && File::exists($dir . $image->image))
                File::delete($dir . $image->image);
            $extension = strtolower($request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $fileName = str_random() . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file('image')->move($dir, $fileName);
            $image->categoryimage = $fileName;
        } elseif ($request->remove == 1 && File::exists('images/' . $image->image)) {
            File::delete('images/' . $image->post_image);
            $image->categoryimage = null;
        }
    }
    $image->categoryname = $request->categoryname;
    $image->save();
    return redirect()->route('categories.index');
}
```

and route

```
Route::match(['get', 'put'], 'category/update/{id}', 'CategoryController@update');
```

and edit form

```
@if(isset($image))
        <form method="PUT" action="http://localhost:8000/category/update/{{$image->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">

<label for="description" class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-lg-2">Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" autofocus placeholder="Description" name="categoryname" type="text" id="categoryname" value="{{ isset($image) ? $image->categoryname : '' }}">



 <label for="image" class="col-form-label col-md-3">Image</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img id="preview"
                             src="{{asset((isset($image) && $image->categoryimage!='')?'images/'.$image->categoryimage:'images/noimage.png')}}"
                             height="200px" width="200px"/>
                        <input class="form-control" style="display:none" name="image" type="file" id="image" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <br/>
                        <a href="javascript:changeProfile();">Add Image</a> |
                        <a style="color: red" href="javascript:removeImage()">Remove</a>
                        <input type="hidden" style="display: none" value="0" name="remove" id="remove">
```

but when I try to update data it is not updating. only refresh to the same page. no, any error

url look like this
`http://localhost:8000/category/update/21?categoryname=tractorrer&image=&remove=0   //tractorrer is updated category name`

how can fix this problem?

Comment: No, any ideas about this matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313033/how-to-use-patch-request-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

You set POST instead of PUT of form method.

Second,

Your codes look a little messy. I updated your action codes;

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    if ($request->isMethod('get')){
        return view('categories.form', ['image' => Category::find($id)]);
    } else{

        $rules = [
              'categoryname' => 'required',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);
        $image = Category::find($id);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $dir = 'images/';
            if ($image->image != '' && File::exists($dir . $image->image))
                File::delete($dir . $image->image);
            $extension = strtolower($request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $fileName = str_random() . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file('image')->move($dir, $fileName);
            $image->categoryimage = $fileName;
        } elseif ($request->remove == 1 && File::exists('images/' . $image->image)) 
        {
            File::delete('images/' . $image->post_image);
            $image->categoryimage = null;
        }

        $image->categoryname = $request->categoryname;
        $image->save();
        return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }
}
```

Can you try again with my directives. I hope it helping your problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### First.

Have you dump all of the request like this to check whether it contains `categoryname`.

`dd($request->all());`

If the `dd` does not print `categoryname` value, then it seems to be the problem when you sending request.

#### Then.

Try using `method="POST"` instead of `method="PUT"` If you have not try yet.
I have never used `PUT` with form submit before

Comment: Then, check the way you send param to your controller. try to use POST instead of PUT. Don't forget to give feed back and vote up if this help!

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few things concerning about your code examples.  Like only having 1 method called `update` for both GET and PUT routes.  Probably not a good habit to get into.  Especially since, if it is a get route, you're not updating anything.  So already the method name / description of what it does, is wrong.

But that aside, you are not seeing anything because you cannot use `method="PUT"` on your form.  You need to use `method="POST"` and then inside your form, you need these lines.  One to tell the form that this is a patch request, and one to put the csrf token in.

```
{{csrf_field()}}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

and I would update your route to PATCH, not PUT.