# Laravel patch method not supported (even on update method)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, httprequest, insert-update

HTML PATCHING FORM

```
{{ Form::model($model , [ 'route' => ['admin.friendship.update', $model->id] , 'class'=>'needs-validation ajax-form', 'method' => 'post' ]) }}
                        @method('PATCH')

   {{ Form::select('user_id' , $users , null , ['id' => 'sender', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}

   {{ Form::select('friend_id' , $users , null , ['id' => 'reciever', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}

   {{ Form::select('status' , ['-2' => -2 , '-1' => -1 , '0' => 0 , '1' => 1] , null , ['id' =>  'status', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}               
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Update method:

```
  public function update(FriendshipsAdminForm $request, Friendship $friendship)
    {
        $friendship->update($request->validated());
        return redirect()->route('admin.friendship.index');
    }
```

Request form

```
class FriendshipsAdminForm extends FormRequest
{
  
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'  => 'required',
            'friend_id'  => 'required',
            'status'  => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('friendship', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FriendshipController::class);
```

This is my form and it's really strange. maybe I can not see a thing that is blocking me from doing this. there is not typo or syntax mistake. **Is there anything about patch method I should consider even when trying update method?**

**UPDATE**

[image]

ERROR MESSAGE , ERROR STATUS 405

**UPDATE2**
I'm using ajax for it.

I'm using ajax the way I use above with near 30 models and all are more complex than this one but all are updating and working nicely but this one is strange

Comment: can you write error message?

Comment: Did you get a server error or an application-level error?

Comment: just updated right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use patch request in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313033/how-to-use-patch-request-in-laravel)

Comment: @ponsfrilus read update2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you using ajax, `@method` is not working in that. You need to activate `PATCH` in your webserver, or change your ajax code to submit form in post and add `_method` in params.
For example in jQuery

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   method: 'POST',
   data:{
        ...
        '_method': 'PATCH',
   }
});
```